# Cannot run Program error=2 on Android while set the NDK Environment

Tags: java, android, android-ndk

I need to compile c++ code on android for using CNN model.

so I try to set the NDK Environment.

I follow this blog for setting NDK Environment http://dev.re.kr/65
but at step 6, error like screen shot occured

I use MacOS Sierra 10.12 and Android Studio 2.2.2 version.

I confirm that the directory jni exists at that path.

[total screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovrLh.png)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, Please read

Comment: ah. if I set the Program ,in Screen shot, to /usr/bin/javah then 
Unable to locate an executable at "/usr/libexec/java_home/bin/javah" (-1) occured...